# How can I traverse through a numpy array in descending order?

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

I have a numpy array called `output` and I want to go through each of the values in descending order.

```
print((output).argsort())
```

gives me

```
[2 3 0 1]
```

The values of `output` are:

```
[-0.00214862  0.05784702 -0.01105899 -0.00507164]
```

What I want is to go through each of the values (starting with `0.05784702`) and check against some function. If it's true, I can stop checking. Or else go to the next.

Comment: Argsort gives you the indexes. You are nearly there. Either sort the array after negating it, or use [::-1] to reverse the indices , and you should be good to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do:

```
for a in reversed(sorted(output)):
    print(a)
```

EDIT: reread your question and realised you wanted it sorted

Comment: That doesn't do it in the right order. It does `-0.005071638, -0.011058992, 0.05784702, -0.002148617`. It should do `0.05784702` first

Comment: Or for more compactness just:

Comment: print(reversed(sorted(output)))

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse sort it :

```
-np.sort(-output)
```

oy you can also reverse the indices

```
output[::-1].sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort it first using [numpy.sort()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) and the flip the obtained result using [numpy.flip()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html), which would return the array in descending order, as in:

```
In [21]: arr
Out[21]: array([-0.00214862,  0.05784702, -0.01105899, -0.00507164])

In [22]: np.flip(np.sort(arr))
Out[22]: array([ 0.05784702, -0.00214862, -0.00507164, -0.01105899])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the parameter `reverse` in the function `sorted()` to `True`:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(4)

for i in sorted(arr, reverse=True):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
3
2
1
0
```